# How do I make single page expiration 1 hour CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, cache, amazon-cloudfront

I am using CloudFront to distribute content from one of my domains.  There is no S3 tie-in here.   By default, content expires after 24 hours, which is fine for most of the data on the website, however, there are a few pages that I'd like to have only a 1 hour cache limit on.  How do I go about setting this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [CloudFront FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/):

> Q. How long will Amazon CloudFront keep my files at the edge
>   locations? By default, if no cache control header is set, each edge
>   location checks for an updated version of your file whenever it
>   receives a request more than 24 hours after the previous time it
>   checked the origin for changes to that file. This is called the
>   “expiration period.” You can set this expiration period as short as 1
>   hour, or as long as you’d like, by setting the cache control headers
>   on your files in your origin. Amazon CloudFront uses these cache
>   control headers to determine how frequently it needs to check the
>   origin for an updated version of that file. If your files don’t change
>   very often, it is best practice to set a long expiration period and
>   implement a versioning system to manage updates to your files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I see a lot of answers say that, but I'm seeing nothing but confusion on *how* to do that(set the cache-control)

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with cache control HTTP headers, you could submit a question that asks for pointers on that.  If you are unfamiliar with how to set HTTP headers in your web server software, you could submit a question for pointers with that, too.  You need to provide more details on what your environment is and what it is that you don't understand.